# Multiple linear regression: true effect and variable specific variation

Tags: regression, estimation, regression-coefficients, simulation

I intend to simulate a population with a single outcome variable and multiple explanatory variables, some of which do have a true effect on the outcome variable and some of which do not. The idea is to be able to simulate a large population from which various samples of different sizes can be drawn, and the results of statistical models can be compared to the true effects of the populations.

I do understand, that I can simulate the data quite easily with a given set of assumed "true" model parameters and an assumed error variance for the entire model. However, in my mind, if I want to simulate a realistic population, the error should not be simulated for the entire model, but for the true parameter of each variable separately. After all, there is always variation in nature, including in the actual effect of a variable, thus the effect of a given variable on the outcome should vary slightly from individual to individual.

If I simulate such data, then shouldn't I have to select a normally distributed beta for each individual observation, rather than fixing the beta to a single value? How would I then go about to compare the estimated beta and its variation to the true beta and its variation? If I am right, the standard error given for each regression coefficient in a multiple regression model does not relate to the natural variation in the true effect, but merely in the uncertainty of the estimate. What I would like to get back, is the estimate in the standard deviation of the simulated beta for each variable.

Thanks already for the input.
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulating data in R for regressions is quite easy using random normal distributions. You can directly formulate the model equation in the generation of random data:

For example, if you want to simulate 1000 people where IV1 has a weak effect on the DV and IV2 has a stronger. IV3 is uncorrelated to the DV but slightly correlated with IV2.

```
iv1 = rnorm(1000,3.5,1)
iv2 = rnorm(1000,3.5,1)
iv3 = rnorm(1000, 2.8+iv2*.2,.8)
dv = rnorm(1000,1+iv1*.1+iv2*.5,.6)
df = data.frame(dv,iv1,iv2,iv3)
```

This creates a dataframe with 1000 persons for which the regression equation is roughly as specified:

```
> summary(lm(dv~iv1+iv2+iv3,data=df))

Call:
lm(formula = dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.73618 -0.42601 -0.02682  0.40399  1.78137 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.02854    0.11283   9.116  < 2e-16 ***
iv1          0.08963    0.01885   4.755 2.27e-06 ***
iv2          0.48254    0.01904  25.346  < 2e-16 ***
iv3          0.01013    0.02349   0.431    0.666    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6016 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4233,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4215 
F-statistic: 243.7 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You'll notice that the B coefficients specified in the random generation (0.1, 0.5, 0.0), as well as the residual standard error (0.6) are quite on point, withstanding random variation.

Just a note on your question: A regression never shows effects for individual observations. It's always on *all* observations. There may be some individuals for which the regression equation does not apply (hence the residual standard error) but you do not specify Betas for individual observations but for all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Martin. I was aware that I can simulate the data for a given model with fixed betas and an overall error. I was more interested in creating a realistic population, where the effect of an IV on the DV can vary slightly, and for which I can attempt to find that variation.

Comment: In that case, you'd either have to create two populations that vary in their effects (i.e. there is a moderating factor) or you just simulate the same dataset with different random seeds and study the random variation of regression effects. You could even make the effect of an IV on the DV dependent on an additional IV by formulating the random distribution accordingly: `dv = rnorm(1000,intercept+iv1*(0.5+0.2*iv2))`. So, you have a moderator which you can now try to find in your regression model.

Comment: That was exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks for the quick and helpful reply.